# Object reference not set to an instance of an object VB.Net OleDbCommand

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013, oledbcommand, oledbdatareader

Everytime i search on my database it always says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Please anyone help me. Thank you.

Here is my code for Search:

`Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click`

```
    If TBSearch.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter keyword to search...", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Keyword to search...")`
        TBSearch.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Call OpenConnection()
    With OleDa
        Call Initialized()
        .SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand() <-------- Error appears here.
        .SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [HighSchool] WHERE [LastName] Like '%%" & TBSearch.Text & "%%' or [FirstName] Like '%%" & TBSearch.Text & "%%' or [MI] Like '%%" & TBSearch.Text & "%%'" & _
        "Or [Gender] Like '%%" & TBSearch.Text & "%%' or [Address] Like '%%" & TBSearch.Text & "%%' or [Birthday] Like '%%" & TBSearch.Text & "%%' or [RNumber] Like '%%" & TBSearch.Text & "%%'" & _
        "Or [ENumber] Like '%%" & TBSearch.Text & "%%'  ORDER By LastName ASC"
        .SelectCommand.Connection = OleCn

        Call PopulateListView()

        If Me.LV.Items.Count >= 1 Then
            MsgBox(Me.LV.Items.Count & " Record(s) found for " & "( " & Me.TBSearch.Text & " )", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Record(s) found...")
        Else
            MsgBox("No record(s) found for " & "( " & Me.TBSearch.Text & " )" & " , please try again... ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "No record found...")
            TBSearch.Focus()
            TBSearch.SelectAll()
        End If
    End With
    Call CloseConnection()
End Sub
```

Here is my code for Populate ListView:

`Public Sub PopulateListView()
        Me.LV.Items.Clear()
        Dim OleDr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        OleDr = OleDa.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader()`

```
    Do While OleDr.Read()
        Dim Item As New ListViewItem
        Item.Text = IIf(OleDr.IsDBNull(0), "", OleDr.Item(0))
        For shtCntr = 1 To OleDr.FieldCount() - 1
            If Not OleDr.IsDBNull(shtCntr) Then
                Item.SubItems.Add(OleDr.Item("FirstName"))
                Item.SubItems.Add(OleDr.Item("LastName"))
                Item.SubItems.Add(OleDr.Item("MI"))
                Item.SubItems.Add(OleDr.Item("Gender"))
                Item.SubItems.Add(OleDr.Item("Address"))
                Item.SubItems.Add(OleDr.Item("Birthday"))
                Item.SubItems.Add(OleDr.Item("RNumber"))
                Item.SubItems.Add(OleDr.Item("ENumber"))
            Else
                Item.SubItems.Add("")
            End If
        Next shtCntr
        Me.LV.Items.Add(Item)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: .SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand() <--- error in here sir

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Did you target x64 or AnyCpu? I think OleDB still only works on 32 bits app. I used to get that error in the past when I tried using OleDB in 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, let's fix some stuff.

1. Don't use `Call`. That's just a hold-over from VB 6 (i.e. the late 90's)
2. Don' use `Exit Sub`. Use `Return` instead. (Same reason as #1)
3. Use parameterized SQL rather that string concatenation. Your code, as is, won't work is someone searches for "O'Mally".

   ```
   Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSearch.Click
       If TBSearch.Text = "" Then
           MsgBox("Please enter keyword to search...", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Keyword to search...")`
           TBSearch.Focus()
           Exit Sub
       End If
       Call OpenConnection()
       With OleDa
           Call Initialized()
           .SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand() 
           .SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [HighSchool] WHERE [LastName] Like @TBSearch or [FirstName] Like @TBSearch or [MI] Like @TBSearch Or [Gender] Like @TBSearch or [Address] Like @TBSearch or [Birthday] Like @TBSearch or [RNumber] Like @TBSearch Or [ENumber] Like @TBSearch ORDER By LastName ASC"
           .SelectCommand.Connection = OleCn
           .SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TBSearch", "%" & TBSearch.Text & "%")

           Call PopulateListView()

           If Me.LV.Items.Count >= 1 Then
               MsgBox(Me.LV.Items.Count & " Record(s) found for " & "( " & Me.TBSearch.Text & " )", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Record(s) found...")
           Else
               MsgBox("No record(s) found for " & "( " & Me.TBSearch.Text & " )" & " , please try again... ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "No record found...")
               TBSearch.Focus()
               TBSearch.SelectAll()
           End If
       End With
       Call CloseConnection()
   End Sub
   ```

As for your error, the only possible cause is that `OleDa` is `Nothing`.

Comment: @user2926827 Please be patient. Please provide the complete error message that you are receiving.

Comment: Are you 100% sure OleDa isn't Nothing? The code I showed won't fix that bug.